# Kendo UI - Click Grid Row to Populate Another Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a **Kendo** grid that when you click on a row, I would like it to update the contents of another grid on the page.  How would you write a function to tell the grid to update the second grid?  As an example, the first grid would be a list of states and the second grid would show all of the cities within the selected state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind the click event on the rows of your first table :

```
$("#states tbody").on("click", "tr", changeState);
```

and then change the data of your second table accordingly :

```
$("#cities").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(getListOfCities());
```

Here is just some sample code : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/UbeXn/1/)

Comment: thanks, i'll give that a try.  it will take some tweaking to work for what i have, but it should work.

Comment: @MichaelDeluca if you want some detailed explanations don't hesitate to put a jsFiddle in a new question (or editing this one) with what you have achieved and what blocking points remains!

Comment: You could also use the grid's change event instead of binding a new one.

Comment: yeah the tricky part is that i'm linking from one sql query to another.  so i need to filter the second table based on the unique identifier being passed from the first table.

Comment: @NunoCarmo no : the event as to be triggered at the click on a row of the first table (not when the content of this table changes...). But it can be bound to the select event if the selection has been enabled...

Comment: @Samuel Caillerie According to docs change event
Fired when the user selects a table row or cell in the grid http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-change

Comment: @NunoCarmo yes, but if you look at the example, this works only if we have activated cell or row selection on the table...